# memory_limit setting in php.ini has no effect from apache

Tags: php, apache

I got an error of "allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted" from a laravel app.  But I still got the same error after I changed memory_limit from 128M to 512M (needless to say that I restarted apache after the change: restart, stop/start, etc. and verified that apache did get restarted).

I checked with phpinfo() in a web page and it showed that the memory_limit is still 128M and the ini file (/etc/php.ini) is the file I changed. But when I ran the command **php -r 'phpinfo();'** from the command line, the memory_limit is 512M.  I checked other ini files in /etc/php.d and all apache config files and none of them set memory_limit for php.

My server runs redhat 8 with apache 2.4.37 and php 7.2.24. Anyone have any ideas what might be going on?  Thanks.

Comment: Couple of things. You probably need to restart the PHP process, too, and not just Apache. Second, running the `php -r` CLI command probably invokes a different php.ini

Comment: @ChrisHaas Thanks. php -r CLI did invoke /etc/php.ini which I changed, but I did need to restart explicitly the php process which is under the name php-fpm. After I restarted php-fpm, phpinfo() from the apache page shows memory_limit 512M now.